# How do I append an existing column to another column, aligning with the indices?

Tags: python, pandas

I have three dataframes that each have different columns, but they all have the same indices and the same number of rows (exact same index). How do I combine them into a single dataframe, keeping each column separate but joining on the indices?

Currently, when I attempt to append them together, I get NaNs and the same indices are duplicated. I created an empty dataframe so that I can put all three dataframes into by append. Maybe this is wrong?

What I am doing is as follows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
frames = a list of the three dataframes  

for x in frames:
    df = df.append(x)
```

Answer (score 1):

DataFrames have a `join` method which does exactly this. You'll just have to modify your code a bit so that you're calling the method from the *real* dataframes rather than the empty one.

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
frames = a list of the three dataframes  

for x in frames:
    df = x.join(df)
```

[More in the docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html#joining-on-index).

Comment: If this answered your question you should click the little check mark by the answer! Some of us are only on StackOverflow for the meaningless rewards.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to come up with a solution by grouping by the index:

`df = df.groupby(df1.index)`

Comment: please post your solution so that future visitors can see what you mean -- otherwise this post has no value.

Comment: df = df.groupby(df1.index), since all of the dataframes shared a common index.

Comment: Could you provide more context like example data, output, and a full (but minimal) working script? It is still very unclear what the problem was and how this solves it.